# Add dropshadow to a TBitmap

Tags: delphi, image-processing, delphi-7, vcl, dropshadow

I have a routine that takes screenshots (TBitmap), I need to add drop-shadow to the final TBitmap/image, I have this code (which used to work but...) something isn't right, the drop-shadow simply isn't drawn:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------- //
procedure TakeScreenshot();
var
   lCapRect : TRect;
   DestBitmap : TBitmap;
begin
     // Take the screenshot & assign it to DestBitmap
     // ...

     // Add the drop shadow to DestBitmap
     DestBitmap.Width  := DestBitmap.Width + 6;
     DestBitmap.Height := DestBitmap.Height + 6;

     PaintShadow(DestBitmap.Canvas, lCapRect);
end;
// --------------------------------------------------------------------- //
procedure PaintShadow(ACanvas : TCanvas; ARect : TRect);
var
   AColor         : TColor;
   i, iMax        : Integer;
   h1, h2, v1, v2 : Integer;
begin
     AColor := ACanvas.Brush.Color;
     iMax   := 6;
     h1     := ARect.Left;
     h2     := ARect.Right;
     v1     := ARect.Top;
     v2     := ARect.Bottom;

     with ACanvas do
     begin
      for i := iMax downto 0 do
      begin
           ACanvas.Pen.Mode := pmMask;
           Pen.Color        := DarkenColorBy(AColor, ((iMax - i) * 4 + 10));

           MoveTo(h1 + 4{i}, v2 + i);
           LineTo(h2 + i + 1, v2 + i);
      end;    // for

      for i := iMax downto 0 do
      begin
           ACanvas.Pen.Mode := pmMask;
           Pen.Color        := DarkenColorBy(AColor, ((iMax - i) * 4 + 10));

           MoveTo(h2 + i, v1 + 4{i});
           LineTo(h2 + i, v2 + i);
      end;    // for
     end;    // with
end;
// --------------------------------------------------------------------- //
function Max(const A, B: Integer): Integer;
begin
     if (A > B) then
    Result  := A
     else
     Result := B;
end;
// --------------------------------------------------------------------- //
function DarkenColorBy(BaseColor : TColor; Amount : Integer) : TColor;
begin
     Result := RGB(Max(GetRValue(ColorToRGB(BaseColor)) - Amount, 0),
           Max(GetGValue(ColorToRGB(BaseColor)) - Amount, 0),
           Max(GetBValue(ColorToRGB(BaseColor)) - Amount, 0));
end;
```

**My question is**: How can I fix this (OR anyone know a simple way to add dropshadow to a TBitmap)?

The final image is meant to be saved as bmp/jpg, not shown in a TImage, so I really need to add drop shadow to the image itself.

PS. I'm using Delphi 7 Pro, my app is restricted to Windows XP or later

**EDIT**

**lCapRect** depends on the settings (whether I'm capturing the active monitor, window or all the desktop monitors), but let's say it's calculated this way:

```
lCapRect.Right  := Screen.DesktopLeft + Screen.DesktopWidth;
lCapRect.Bottom := Screen.DesktopTop + Screen.DesktopHeight;
lCapRect.Left   := Screen.DesktopLeft;
lCapRect.Top    := Screen.DesktopTop;
```

The bitmap does contain the screenshot (+ 6 pixels added to the bottom & right sides to make room for the dropshadow), it's just that the drop shadow drawing doesn't happen

Comment: What are you passing for 'lCapRect'?

Comment: I would recommend GDI+ (http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus/index.shtml) which has the capabilty of creating brushes with an alpha value, but unfortunately it's D2009 and up only

Comment: @AlanClark: Thanks, I'm afraid I need this for Delphi 7 :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown how you are calculating `lCapRect`. For not drawing off the bitmap regarding your `PaintShadow` procedure, it has to be smaller than the bitmap, example:

```
lCapRect := DestBitmap.Canvas.ClipRect;

// Add the drop shadow to DestBitmap
DestBitmap.Width  := DestBitmap.Width + 6;
DestBitmap.Height := DestBitmap.Height + 6;

PaintShadow(DestBitmap.Canvas, lCapRect);
```

Comment: I edited my post regarding lCapRect. I added 6 pixels to both bottom/right sides to make room for the dropshadow effect

Comment: @Gdhami - Don't calculate lCapRect independantly, you already have a bitmap with a definite size. Have you tried the code in the answer?

Comment: You're right, I didn't pay attention to the Canvas.ClipRect assignement, the drop shadow is a bit ugly, but that's a different story and at least now the drawing occur, thanks man!